# Who snitched in X-Men: Apocalypse and why?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

So my question is based in the scene where “Henryk” aka Magneto saves the life of one of the men in the steel factory. He moves the steel canister so it doesn’t fall and kill the man when the chain snaps. We know this already.

My question is why would somebody tell on him for using his powers to save that man's life?

Comment: Well the guy DID threaten a whole lot of other people. Maybe the snitch thought "he saved a guy, but killed many others, better not risk it". Or, you know, plain old racism.

Comment: Well my point was that if somebody saves somebody else you’d think they’d changed. And I wouldn’t want to tell because if he escaped which he did then he’d come back on me

Comment: I agree with you, but that probably not everyone's case (in-universe) (but sadly, also out-of-universe). About retaliation, do we ever learn who snitched? I can't remember. In any case, this might fall under "everybody in the whole small town knows it overnight". Seriously, the less people there are the faster the info spreads, and you can't always trace it back to the source...

Comment: Maybe there was a reward out for what might be considered public enemy #1

Comment: If I saw Bin Laden save somebody from death, still no way I would just think "ok, I'll go on working with him, seems a fine guy now."

Comment: @SergeSeredenko. Bin Laden is a totally different type of person. He would most likely be saving one of his own people if any. Magneto saved a human not one of his own people and he was in Poland not his home country so not one of his people. So this shows he went out of his way to save somebody.

Comment: Reminder, everyone: Answer in answers, not in comments. Comments are potentially temporary, and don't have any of the mechanisms to ensure quality responses that answers do.

Comment: @K.Lanie Poland WAS hist home country and he was raised as 'one of them' and he's quite a kind of Osama type, honestly...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems likely that the person who "snitched" on Magneto was this guy who saw him extend his hand and then look around suspiciously.

[image]

As to what *motivated* him to talk to the police, we can't really say but the general consensus seems to be that Magneto is a vicious murderer and would-be assassin of world leaders rather than a misunderstood advocate for mutant rights.

> **Police Chief:** *Nobody in this town really knows you*.
>
> **Magneto:** *Yes you do. I am Henryk Gurszky. Jakob, I've had dinner in your home...*
>
> **Jakob:** *And you were lying the whole time. I brought a killer into my house.*

The news article held by the policeman talks about Magneto being **an existential threat to the entire world.**

[image]
<sub><sup>*"M-Day. 10 years Ago. The day on which which the mutants saved the world".*</sup></sub>

Comment: "The day on which mutants saved the world" and "an existential threat to the entire world" do not compute. Mistranslation?

Comment: @muru - Magneto isn't the particular mutant that saved the world.

Comment: @muru: Those two things are certainly not mutually exclusive. The Avengers saved the world more than once but there are entire MCU plotlines dedicated to the problem of controlling such a powerful force, a force which can _and has_ presented an existential threat to the entire world by their actions. Closer to home, one might potentially argue that nuclear weapons "saved the world" (or at least brought an end to a potentially devastating war) but I think we can all agree they're not the safest things to have lying around.

Comment: @Lightness probably. But when you see a headline that says mutants saved the world (the headline is about all that's readable here, I think) and a photo prominently showing a mutant beneath it, but somebody then uses that article to claim that that mutant is an existential threat, you honestly wouldn't wonder if you're missing something?

Comment: @muru: Maybe if I hadn't read the article

Comment: Mutants save the world from other mutants. I'm sure the articles will talk about magneto.

Comment: @BernardtheBear - The thing that was going to destroy the world was actually Trask's robots....under the control of a single rogue mutant.

Comment: Robots were tools just like guns just more powerful. People kill people with guns, the person is the killer not the gun.

Comment: @BernardtheBear - Take away the gun and people can't kill others as easily.

Comment: Still doesn't make the robots the killers, but the person using the robot. He wants to kill because he feels humans are the enemy. I still won't trust a terrorist who claims to be reformed.

Answer (score 45):

I would like to give more context regarding *why* exactly the snitch would be so eager to come out with his knowledge of his workmate's superpowers.

At that moment of the movie (1983), the action's set in Polish People's Republic, time of great political turmoil - sort of [*Sturm und Drang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_und_Drang) moment. Workplaces were being infiltrated by intelligence and secret service, because those were the places where the first countrywide union ([Solidarność](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidarno%C5%9B%C4%87)) was emerging and building up its power. Instead, some folk saw it as an opportunity to gain financial advantage, as snitching was a paid hustle here back then.

So to answer your question: history and context made the man/snitch.

Comment: I thought your answer was amazing as well friend thank you for writing it hence I pressed the up button for you as well.

Comment: The title asks who, but the question asks why. If the question is why, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @dna - I'm not so sure. Does supposition (however well supported by background knowledge) trump what we actually see in the film?